# CSS No-Show in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to set up a CSS page so the my PHP site has background and basics. However, the CSS doesn't show up, although direct style modifications to the HTML code work fine.

Here's the CSS:

```
    body {
        background-color: #FF9900;
    }

    h1 {
       color: #6600FF;
       font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    }

    #passwd_result{
        background:#FF9900;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-right:60%;
    }

    #upload_result{
        background:#CC3300;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-right:60%;
    }
```

And this is the index page with the CSS reference:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    echo "<h1 align='center'> Welcome to Metube! </h1>";
    ?>

    <form action="login.php" method="post" align="center">

        <input type="submit" class="button"  VALUE = "Log in" >
    </form>

    <form action="register.php" method="post" align="center">

        <input type="submit" class="button"  VALUE = "Register" >
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You aren't using the IDs in the HTML so any CSS attached to them won't work. Also `align` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's network monitor to ensure the CSS file is being loaded?

Comment: What HTML tutorial are you using? I recommend you not use anything written in the late 90's/early 00's. It is outdated. I would recommend something like [htmldog.com](http://htmldog.com/) -- always been one of the better websites out there.

Comment: It's basically not showing up right now. Paulie_D, how do you mean for the IDs? Shouldn't it be automatic when the CSS is loaded?

Comment: from where the index file is, do you have a folder named css with the default.css file in it? There is no PHP so it seems, just HTML?

Comment: `#upload_result` associates with the HTML attribute `id` which should have the value `upload_result`. Same with `passwd_result`.

Comment: RST, yes, the file is in a subfolder marked css, but there is some php in the file. chris85, I understand that, but I don't know why the "body" section isn't changing the body tag in the php file.